# PhantomJS: Unexpected nSyntaxError: Unexpected token '>' in GitlabCI

Tags: angular, unit-testing, phantomjs, karma-jasmine, gitlab-ci

I am trying to run unit/ui tests in an Angular app with Karma and Jasmine in GitlabCI.
When I'm using chrome, everything is ok, but when I use phantomJS, after all tests pass I get the following error:

> PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
>   {
>       "message": "An error was thrown in afterAll\nSyntaxError: Unexpected token '>'",
>       "str": "An error was thrown in afterAll\nSyntaxError: Unexpected token '>'"
>   }

Even though I don't have any `afterAll` method. I saw that this might be connected with PhantomJS not supporting ES6. But I cannot find a clear way how to
a) Fix the issue
b) Use different browser to run it in GitlabCI (I see there is Chrome Headless but I cannot find on how to use it in GitlabCI)

Help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: PhantomJS is deprecated so I suggest you use Chrome or Firefox driver with headless mode. Not sure about GitlabCl but you need to set the start up options for headless mode.

Comment: Thanks, my problem was that I was looking for some advanced configuration no ChromeHeadless that I didn't realize it is not needed. After switching to Chromium Headless everything works fine :)